# Add HTML code using CSS

Tags: css

**html**

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

I want to add HTML code into this div (see following result I want) using **ONLY CSS**

```
<div id="mydiv"><a href="#">Lorem</a></div>
```

I think :after and :before are not helpful here!

Comment: It's not possible, CSS isn't markup language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS is not HTML. It is **not possible** to achieve that as CSS is not a markup language.

Just to add you can add content but not the element using `:before or :after` pseudo-element. Refer the **[specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content)**

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this for many reasons.

Firstly its just wrong.

Secondly it is not possible.

Css is not for markup html is.

and I dont even understand why you would want to do this at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [content](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html) (just for text) in a couple of browsers but it's a really bad idea. Please solve this differently e.g. with Javascript, you'll need to for HTML anyway.